# Qt Whenever pressed enter in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, events, qtextedit

Whenever I pressed enter in my QTextEdit it'll perform a click on my login button. Somehow this causes a crash of my QtCreator. How can I change what'll happen If I press enter in my QTextEdit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to subclass `QTextEdit` and catch the event you're interested in by overriding the appropriate method:

```
class MyTextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void MyTextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Return)
        {
            login(); // or rather emit submitted() or something along this way
        }
        else
        {
            QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
        }
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you can [install an event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on the text edit.